# Powershell - add elements to XML file if

Tags: powershell, element

I have an xml file which container provider information. I need to check if there is an "AddressType" defined within each AddressRow. If the AddressRow is defined (one of 3 types - HQ, SUB, MAIN) then all is OK. If there is no an AddressRow present, then I need to add the missing AddressType element and a description to go with it.

This is the sample XML file. Which has got 2 providers shown.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OrganisationUnits>
  <OrganisationUnitsRow num="1">
    <OrganisationId>001</OrganisationId>
    <OrganisationName>Provider 001</OrganisationName>
    <Addresses>
      <AddressesRow num="1">
        <AddressType>HQ</AddressType>
        <AddressTypeDesc>Headquarters</AddressTypeDesc>
      </AddressesRow>
      <AddressesRow num="2">
        <MainAddress>N</MainAddress>
        <AddressType>SUB</AddressType>
        <AddressTypeDesc>Sub Office</AddressTypeDesc>
      </AddressesRow>
    </Addresses>
  </OrganisationUnitsRow>
  <OrganisationUnitsRow num="2">
    <OrganisationId>002</OrganisationId>
    <OrganisationName>Provider 002</OrganisationName>
    <Addresses>
      <AddressesRow num="1">
        <MainAddress>Y</MainAddress>
        <NonStandardAddress>
          <LocationId>P520851</LocationId>
          <PostCode>G20 9RQ</PostCode>
        </NonStandardAddress>
      </AddressesRow>
      <AddressesRow num="2">
        <MainAddress>N</MainAddress>
        <NonStandardAddress>
          <LocationId>P526750</LocationId>
        </NonStandardAddress>
      </AddressesRow>
    </Addresses>
  </OrganisationUnitsRow>
</OrganisationUnits>
```

The first provider has got 2 address rows each with a correct AddressType of SUB and HQ.
The second provider has 2 AddressRows but not AN AddressType defined. Therefore my script should add a default address Type of "DEF" with a description of "Default Address".

```
<AddressesRow num="1">
    <MainAddress>Y</MainAddress>
    <NonStandardAddress>
        <LocationId>P520851</LocationId>
        <PostCode>G20 9RQ</PostCode>
    </NonStandardAddress>
    <AddressType>DEF</AddressType>
    <AddressTypeDesc>Default Address</AddressTypeDesc>
</AddressesRow>
```

This is my code which does not seem to be adding the new elements.

```
$Path = "C:\DEV\sandpit\small.xml"
$xml = [xml](Get-Content $path)

$node = $xml.OrganisationUnits.OrganisationUnitsRow.Addresses.AddressesRow

foreach($AddressType in $node)
{

    if ($AddressType.'#text' -ne "HQ" -or $AddressType.'#text' -ne "SUB" -or $AddressType.'#text' -ne "MAIN" ) 
    {
        $AddType = $xml.CreateElement("AddressType")
        $AddType.set_InnerXML("DEF")
        $AddTypeDesc = $xml.CreateElement("AddressTypeDesc")
        $AddTypeDesc.set_InnerXML("Default Address")

        $xml.OrganisationUnits.OrganisationUnitsRow.Addresses.AddressesRow.AppendChild($AddType, $AddTypeDesc)


    }
}

$xml.Save($path)
```

I cant see why its not behaving as expected - its not adding the new elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're currently testing against the InnerText of the `AddressRow` node itself rather than each `AddressType` child node.

You first need to check whether the `AddressType` node even exists, then look at the text:

```
foreach($addressRow in $xml.OrganisationUnits.OrganisationUnitsRow.Addresses.AddressesRow)
{
    if(-not $addressRow.Item('AddressType') -or $addressRow.Item('AddressType')."#text" -notin @('HQ','SUB'))
    {
        $newAddressType = $xml.CreateElement('AddressType')
        $newAddressType.InnerText = 'DEF'

        $newAddressTypeDesc = $xml.CreateElement('AddressTypeDesc')
        $newAddressTypeDesc.InnerText = 'Default Location'

        $newAddressType,$newAddressTypeDesc |ForEach-Object {
            $addressRow.AppendChild($_)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mathias, working perfectly (once I upgraded my powershell version to 3.0)